# Unable to build a console application in ASP.NET 5 dnx

Tags: c#, debian, asp.net-core, dnx

I am unable to build the following application on Debian with Visual Studio Code. What am I missing?

> project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ParseAB2Steps Console Application",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "ParseAB2Steps"
  },

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "commands": {
    "ParseAB2Steps": "ParseAB2Steps"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ParseAB2Steps
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to read ab2steps.md");
            Console.Read();

            string ab2steps = File.ReadAllText("/home/ab2/Dropbox/nodes/ab2/ab2-steps.md");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error on `dnu build`:

> /home/ab2/projects/ParseAB2Steps/Program.cs(13,31):
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in
>   the current context
>
> Build failed.

Note: I put the System.IO line in the project.json manually by copying the version from the previous line and was able to do the `dnu restore` successfully.

I am also aware of the new `dotnet` cli and I did not upgrade to it as Debian is not directly supported as far as I know. So, I am using the `dnx` environment which I currently have.

Edit 2:

> Output of `dnvm list`

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          linux           
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx       default
       1.0.0-rc2-16312      mono                 linux/osx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the dependency from `System.IO` to `System.IO.FileSystem` did the trick for me.

You can leave `System.IO` in the file as well, but it's brought in anyway since it's a dependency of a few of the other assemblies, including `System.Console` and `System.IO.FileSystem`.

Comment: In `project.json`, I changed `System.IO` to `System.IO.FileSystem` and version number as suggested by intellisense to `4.0.1-beta-23516`. I still get the following error when I do the `dnu build`: `DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: `dnu restore` is done by the way, after changing `project.json`

Comment: Okay, I changed the dependency again to `"System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1-beta-23516"` and did a `dnu restore` and this time I was able to compile successfully.